# ng-class not working well on the binding variable if toggled quickly, Is that possible?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am facing the following problem:

```
<input 
    type = "text" 
    class = "class1 class2" 
    placeholder = "Type here..." 
    autocomplete = "off" 
    ng-model = "searchKeyword" 
    name = "searchId"
    ng-class = "{'my-class1': myObject.myAttribute,'my-class2': myObject.myFunction()}" //<-- HERE IS THE PROBLEM
    ng-disabled = "myObject.myFunction()"
    ng-change = "searchConditionChanged()" numbers-only />
```

Most of time `myObject.myFunction()` will return false, but there is a short period that it returns true.

On my web page, I can see the class `"my-class2"` is added to `<input>` correctly, but after that the class should be removed when `myObject.myFunction()` returns false again.

But the question is why the "my-class2" class is added, but **NOT** removed. The class is still in DOM tree, when I see the function return false in `console.log()`.

It will not change, even if I use `$scope.$apply()` or `$scope.$digest()` to force update.

Class "my-class1" binds to `myObject.myAttribute`. It has the same problem.

Something else that confuses me a lot is that when true is returned from `myObject.myFunction()` lasts a little longer (like 500ms), ng-class always set class correctly.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that how to write you code,the best way to paste you controller or method;
I think do this maybe make this problem :

1. in you code, you only act my-class on start time, and then never
   action;
2. you code maybe complex so much make the period so long;
3. you change the value but not bind to view;

my example goes well

```js
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []).controller('haha', function ($scope, $timeout) {
   $scope.user = {
    name: 'admin'
   };
   $timeout(function loop() {
     if ($scope.user.name) {
      $scope.user.name = '';
      console.log($scope.user.name);
     } else {
      $scope.user.name = 'admin';
      console.log($scope.user.name);
     }
     $timeout(loop, 5)
    }, 5)
  })
```

```css
.r {
   color: red;
   font-size: 30px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="haha">
  <div ng-class="{'r':user.name}">{{user.name}}</div>
</div>
```